# Fix "kexec" error (failure, problem, broken) that prevents (unable to) "npm install" WebPack etc "node_modules" dir after node upgrade (node 12,13,14)

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

I upgraded "node" to "node 14", and ran an "npm install", but the install failed because of an error while attempting to compile "kexec" (a.k.a. "node-kexec"); which is required by "WebPack".

Error messages include:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/my_self/my_project/node_modules/kexec
...
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/kexec.cc:14:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2884:
...etc...
npm ERR! ../src/kexec.cc:19:11: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
...etc...
npm ERR! 1 warning and 9 errors generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/kexec/src/kexec.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
...etc...
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

This issue only shows up for projects that have a dependency upon "kexec".  The actual purpose of "kexec" is to launch programs by passing a request to the OS, either directly or through a shell like "bash".

As it happens, WebPack depends upon "kexec".  So to get WebPack working with "node" versions 12, 13, 14, etc, "kexec" has to compile.

This problem has already been documented and fixed on GitHub.  In fact, there is a radically new version of "kexec" available, waiting for a "pull" to the master branch.  The problem is that the "pull" has languished.

How can use the fixed version of "kexec" within my "npm install" to rebuild the "node_modules" directory as required by "WebPack"?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully get a revised version of "kexec" (a.k.a. "node-kexec") to compile via "npm install" despite an upgrade to "node" (node 14), the result being well built "node_modules" fulfilling requirements for "WebPack".

If using "npm" version "8.3.0" or higher, try using "overrides".  See "Candidate Method 3", below.  In my case, I didn't explore using "overrides" becasue I am using a version of "npm" that does not have the capability.  Instead, I did some trickery.

The required version of "kexec" is 3.0.0, but that is old code which breaks when "node" is upgraded to or beyond "node" version 12.

An all new "kexec" 4.0.0 has been written.  The re-write was available back in Oct 2020, but as of Jan 26, 2022, the revision is still languishing.  The new code is awaiting a "pull" into the "master" branch.  This v4.0.0 fixes the problem, except for the fact that "npm" can't find it.

"WebPack" requirements call for "kexec" v3.0.0; which is the broken version.  It can't find v4.0.0 because it's not in the master branch.  The obvious solution would be to convince "npm" to look elsewhere for "kexec".  Some transparent override methods are described here.  These methods involve modifying the "package.json" file; (hence, transparency).  Later in this answer, I also describe a non-transparent method; this "trickery" is what worked for me.

**Method 1** with package.json: Use "yarn" and "resolutions"

As per "tamlyn", Jul 15, 2020, "if you're using Yarn...[add] the following to your package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "kexec": "meteor/node-kexec#update-for-node-12"
  }
```

But this does not fit my situation, since I am using "npm", and not "yarn".

**Method 2** with package.json: Use "npm" and "npm-force-resolutions"

There is a module "npm-force-resolutions" that attempts to make the above mentioned "resolutions" idea work with "npm".  However, the word is that it works only with older versions of "npm".

**Method 3** with package.json: Use "npm" and "overrides"

For "npm" version 8.3.0, there is a built in feature called "overrides" that is supposed to be the equivalent of "resolutions".  Here is the documentation for it:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Presumably, the syntax for use would be like that shown above for "yarn", but with the word "overrrides" replacing "resolutions".  If you are using a version of "npm" that is v8.3.0 or higher, you should try this.  I did not explore this.

**Non-Transparent Method**

If possible, start by upgrading to the latest version of "npm".

```
$ sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

And then check the "npm" and "node" versions.  In my case, because several machines need to be coordinated, I did not have the absolute latest.  Here is what I was working with:

```
$ npm --version
v7.12.0

$ node --version
v14.18.3
```

Having sufficiently upgraded "npm", you are ready to actually start fixing the "kexec" problem.  If you have "npm" version 8.3.0 or more, try "Method 3", mentioned above.  If that doesn't work, proceed as follows.

In this documentation, I will use the word "my_project_dir" to represent the directory in which you are trying to create your "node_modules" sub-directory.  Start by going to that location.

```
$ cd my_project_dir
```

Move aside the existing "node_modules" directory (if any exists).

```
$ mv node_modules node-modules-old
```

You should now attempt a fresh install.  Of course, this install will look at "package.json" or "package-lock.json", and know what is needed.  However, presuming your development environment requires "kexec", and because the old "kexec" has trouble compiling within the new "node" environment, the install hits a wall; as shown here

```
$ npm install
...
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kexec/src/kexec.o] Error 1
... etc,
... etc, etc, more "build error" messages
```

In my case, I use "WebPack", which has a dependency on "kexec v3.0.0", which breaks when used with upgraded "node".

The totally new version of "kexec", which is the creation of a group of developers at "Meteor", is available on "github", directly through one of the developers, who goes by the user-name "StorytellerCZ".  (See also list of URLs at end of this doc).

Use "git" to download the updated code.  Actually, what I did was a "git clone" of the entire "node-kexec" module repository, as presented by "StorytellerCZ".  This download has more than is needed, but that's ok.

```
$ pwd
/home/myself/my_project_dir
```

A "node_modules" sub-directory exists; it was created by the attempted "npm install".  Descend into the sub-directory.

```
$ cd node_modules

$ git clone https://github.com/StorytellerCZ/node-kexec.git
```

This creates a sub-directory named "node-kexec"; which is a "git" repository.  Note that the desired directory name is actually "kexec", but, for now, having two different names ("kexec" versus "node-kexec") will actually keeps things cleaner.

The next step depends upon whether a "kexec" directory already exists.  Check for it.

```
$ ls -ld kexec
drwxr-xr-x  16 myself  staff  512 Apr 30  2021 kexec
```

The "kexec" subdiretory might not exist; this depends upon what was left over from the failed "install"; (the "install" that got you looking for a fix in the first place).  On my Mac OS X (BSD) system with "npm --version" of "7.12.0", the "kexec" remnant was preserved.  On an AWS Linux system with "npm --version" of "6.14.15", the "kexec" directory was destroyed at every failed "npm install".

If the "kexec" directory exists, you just need to cherry-pick one file from the git clone.  First move the old file asside; the following command moves the old file to a new name where-in "-2016" is a reminder of the year of the most recent "pull" of the source code for "kexec".

```
$ mv kexec/src/kexec.cc kexec/src/kexec-2016.cc
```

Now replace that with the desired version

```
$ cp -p node-kexec/src/kexec.cc kexec/src
```

And remove the clone, so that it doesn't cause problems at some later date.

```
$ rm -rf node-kexec
```

On the other hand, if "kexec" is not present as a subdirectory, then you must convert the "node-kexec" repository into a directory that is named "kexec".

```
$ mv node-kexec kexec
```

However, you probably need to do one more thing; a bit of subterfuge.  The package dependencies for your project might include a requirement for **exactly** version "3.0.0" of "kexec"; this is the case for my project, which I assume is because of some dependancy of "WebPack".  The "kexec" from "StorytellerCZ" is labeled as version "4.0.0"; (and indeed, it is an entirely new body of code).  This is problematic, because, on some systems, "npm" will actually delete the subdirectory you just created, and replace it with the same old, bad "3.0.0" code.  Therefore, some subterfuge is necessary.

To trick the "npm" system into accepting the new directory, edit the "package.json" file, and modify the value of the "version" parameter to "3.0.0".  Yes, this really stinks, but it solves the immediate problem.  (The real solution will be for the "4.0.0" changes to finally get integrated into the "master" branch.)  The following steps make the change, cautiously.

Descend into pre-existing "kexec" directory, under "node_modules".

```
$ cd kexec
```

Make a copy of the file you are about to change.  This leaves a clue for you, in the future, when you are wondering how the version number got the way it is.

```
$ cp -p package.json package.json-original
```

Edit the "package.json" file.  For example, if your editor is "vim", you could invoke the editor like this:

```
$ vim package.json
```

Change the "version" value; make it "3.0.0".  When that's done, save the edit and quit the editor.

Ascend out of the "kexec" sub-directory, back to "node_modules".

```
$ cd ..
```

So, at this point you have prepared a "kexec" module that should compile.  You did it one of two ways: either (1) you had a pre-existing "kexec" directory and you simply copied over the updated "kexec.cc" file, or (2) you renamed "node-kexec" to "kexec" and you fiddled with the "version" number.

To re-try your install, first ascend out of the "node_modules" sub-directory, back to your project directory.

```
$ cd ..
```

Prove to yourself that this is the right place.

```
$ pwd
/home/myself/my-project-dir
```

Do the install.

```
$ npm install
```

The "kexec" error should be gone.

If you are still getting errors, check whether the very first line of warning message says the following:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
```

This warning should go away when you upgrade the "npm" version to 7.12.0 or better.  Do so!

If "npm" protests about the presence of "git" information, that should go away once you upgrade the "npm" version to 7.12.0 or better.  If the warning persists, then you can just get rid of the "git" info, as follows.

Descend into the repository dir

```
$ cd kexec  # formerly named "node-kexec"
```

Confirm, just for fun, that the "git" structure is actually here.  Note that "ls *" won't show hidden files, hence use this command:

```
$ ls -a | grep git  
.git
.gitignore
```

Strip out the git repository information.

```
$ rm -rf .git
$ rm .gitignore
```

Ascend out of the "kexec" sub-directory, back to "node_modules".

```
$ cd ..

$ pwd
/home/myself/my-project-dir/node_modules
```

Retry the "npm install".

---

Appendix I

Here are some URLs to relevant github archives:

```
[https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec/issues/36][1]

[https://github.com/StorytellerCZ/node-kexec.git][1]

[https://github.com/meteor/node-kexec/tree/update-for-node-12][1]
```

---

Appendix II

On OS-X, the intermediate binary object file created during the build is:

```
node_modules/kexec/build/Release/obj.target/kexec/src/kexec.o
```

On OS-X, the executable appears to be:

```
node_modules/kexec/build/Release/kexec.node
```

On AWS Linux, I did not find either of those.  I didn't bother to
seek an explanation, since WebPack had become functional, and
therefore my goal was achieved.